# Is there a way to implement an on loaded event for a content view in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

There doesn't seem to be an on loaded event for the content view and I can't seem to find a way to override the on appearing method either. Is there a way to implement on loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment this is not possible.

There's a feature request in Github issues asking for this. You can follow it here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3486 and here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2210.

In the meantime, you can make (a quite dirty hack) two public methods and call these from your `OnAppearing()` / `OnDissapearing()` Page callbacks.

```
<local:MyContentView x:Name="MyContentView" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100">            
</local:MyContentView>
```

Code-behind on Page

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    (MyContentView as MyContentView)?.PageAppearing();
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    (MyContentView as MyContentView)?.PageDisappearing();
}
```

Your ContentView:

```
public partial class MyContentView : ContentView
{
    public MyContentView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void PageAppearing()
    {
    }

    public void PageDisappearing()
    { 
    }
}
```

Note: If you are doing this for many `ContentView` there might be an improvement to this code like using an Interface that your ContentViews will implement and use that one to do the casting from the Page.

Hope this gives you an idea.